# Parse attribute value before pass in model

Tags: php, model, yii2, attributes, behavior

I would like to implement a content parser in a post model, which parse the content before pass it to controller. So, I think the best solution is a behavior to manage this, but I didnt find an EVENT for this.

I do not want to write the value to the DB, but I would like to parse the loaded value before pass it to the controller.

Any idea?

Comment: if you mean that you want to modify an already saved value in the database after retrieving it for viewing purpose only, and passing to the `controller/action` you might be looking for `afterFind()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Muhammad Omer Aslam , `afterFind()` according to documentation,

> is called when the ActiveRecord object is created and populated with the query
>   result. The default implementation will trigger an
>   [[EVENT_AFTER_FIND]] event.

Sometimes I have had the need to format a property of my model before visualizing it or using it in any other action of the controller. The problem is solved by overriding `afterFind()` in the model.

For example, to format the creation date of a certain object before viewing it, we can write the following in the corresponding model.

```
public function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();
    /* change format date */
    $parse = Yii::$app->formatter;
    $this->created_at = $parse->asDate($this->created_at, 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```